# Clone a thread in .Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading

Is it possible to make a copy of a thread in .Net? Kind of like a fork() but on just a thread instead of the whole process?

I have a recursive algorithm, and for testing purposes I wan't to evaluate several different branches that the code can take. The easiest way would be to clone the thread at the decision point in the code and let each thread continue in a different branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My research didn't turn up any answers, and the lack of responses here leads me to the conclusion that it can't be done.

So no, there is no method to copy/fork a thread in .Net.

Answer (score 1):

Any recursive algorithm can be implemented as an iterative algorithm with the help of a stack object (as in [System.Collections.Stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack.aspx)). Then your question becomes one of cloning the Stack object (trivial), as opposed to cloning the thread and it's stack state (difficult).

Comment: True, but the algorithm is large and already exists. I wanted to do this for testing purposes only, so it would not be pertinent to re-write the code.

Comment: even if you manage to clone a managed thread, the cloned thread stack will contain references to managed objects (handles).  It is highly unlikely that the algorithm will properly synchronize access to these objects. More important the clone will be a shallow clone, due to these handles, as opposed to a deep clone which is what you probably really want.